# Change aspect ratio of casted content on Samsung TV

Tags: ios, swift, samsung-smart-tv

I am using [smart-view-sdk](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/extension-libraries/smart-view-sdk/download.html) to cast photo and video from iPhone to samsung tv.
It casts succesfully but image and video is resized and fills the full screen. I don't want that. Is there any way to not resize the content?

Here is my code for casting photo.

```
// mediaURL is the link of an image
let player = service.createPhotoPlayer("demo")
player?.addToList(mediaURL)

player?.playContent(mediaURL, title: "demo", completionHandler: { error in
            
})
```